# nicedit tool works fine on my localhost, but when uploading the site to the cloud it doen't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, textarea, nicedit

I have installed Nicedit tool to convert `<textarea>` into **richtext box** on my pages by adding the following code as per their instructions on their website:

```
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
```

However textareas got convereted (Nicedit worked fine) ONLY on my localhost Xampp, but when i uploaded the pages online, everything works fine except for the Nicedit, it doesn't work at all.

Please note that no error messages appeared, nor with textareas the issue is that textareas appear plain just like the standard, like if I didn't install the Nicedit.

Note: I have tried the following code as well since I've seen it as an example on their page, but it doesn't work also.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
  //]]>
  </script>.
```

PHP version used online is 5.6, if this would be useful info.

Comment: Just for my understanding, I know that JS is client based therefore changing the server (between localhost and online cloud) shouldn't change the behavior of the script provided that it was run on the same browser client, then why the script works on my localhost only? what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't find the reason to fix the issue that I have, I've found another tool created by the same programmer of Nicedit, it's name is CKeditor.
it's really nice, however browsing the website would take you into the direction of downloading and using JS code from your site, but I have found the following way to let it work as CDN.

First in the `<head></head>` tags copy the following:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.1/basic/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

then inside `<body></body>` copy this code (presuming **text1** is the **name** arttibute for the `<textarea>` that you want to convert.

```
<script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'text1');
</script>
```

Hope this would be helpful for everyone.